# can not upgrade 16.04 to 17.04

Tags: 16.04, 17.04

what I have tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo update-mamanger -d
```

restarted computer

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

restarted computer then ran software updater Upgrade

```
third party sources disabled -- closed
start upgrade
Failed to lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Is there some thing else to try?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file.

Mine has this line:

```
 Prompt=lts
```

I can only upgrade to the next LTS release.

It should match your options in the graphical update manager tool, but in the Unix world, everything is a file. Therefore there's nothing like a good old command line.